# Print formatted key and [key, value] from Dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, printing, swift4

I would like to know how to print key and value from Dictionary.

My grouped dictionary:

```
var Grouped: [String? : [(key: String, value: String?)]]
```

How it prints right now.

```
("9:00 - 22:00", [(key: "II", value: Optional("9:00 - 22:00")), (key: "III", value: Optional("9:00 - 22:00")), (key: "IV", value: Optional("9:00 - 22:00"))])

("7:00 - 22:00", [(key: "I", value: Optional("7:00 - 22:00"))])
("Closed", [(key: "VII", value: Optional("Closed"))])

("9:00 - 21:00", [(key: "V", value: Optional("9:00 - 21:00"))])

("10:00 - 20:00", [(key: "VI", value: Optional("10:00 - 20:00"))])
```

Is it possible to print values like that:

```
"9:00 - 22:00" - "II", "III", "IV"

"7:00 - 22:00" - "I"

"Closed" - "VII"

"9:00 - 21:00" - "V"

"10:00 - 20:00" - "VI"
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print using the quotes:

```
for case let key? in grouped.keys {
    let values = grouped[key]!.map { "\"" + $0.key + "\""}.joined(separator: ", ")
    print("\"" + key + "\"", "-", values)
}
```

example output:

> ```
> "10:00 - 20:00" - "VI"
> "9:00 - 22:00" - "II", "III", "IV"
> "7:00 - 22:00" - "I"
> "Closed" - "VII"
> "9:00 - 21:00" - "V"
> ```

Bear in mind that a dictionary is an unordered collection and so the lines may print in a different order each time

Comment: Thanks for your reply, everything worked! Now I'll try to figure out what it does.